# What is the timestamp format followed in FTP FSH in datapower?

Tags: timestamp, ibm-datapower

In datapower When a FTP poller front side handler is used, the poller renames the input file in the following format : filename . hostname . serial . domain . poller . timestamp. I need to know the format of timestamp ( eg: hh:mm:sss ) it will use for writing the file. Please don't ask me to try and check as i don't have access to it.

Comment: Sorry, me neither. Only hope would be that it is mentioned somewhere in the [infocenter at ibm's website](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SS9H2Y)

Comment: I couldn't find it in Infocenter site as well.